# Unable to call a controller action method using Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am beginner to jquery-ajax. I trying to get Employee data into front-end using ajax method. But the url is not calling the action method. Please check the below code

MyScripts.js:

```
function fn_test()
{
    var eno = $("#t1").val();

    $.ajax({
        cache :false,
        url: "Home/GetEmpData/"+eno,
        type: 'GET',
        data:"",
        contentType:'application/json;',
        success: function (response)
        {
            var str = "Ename :" + response.EmpName + "<br >";
            str += "Job :" + response.Job + "<br >";
            tr += "Salary :" + response.Salary + "<br >";
            str += "Deptno :"+response.DeptNo+"<br >";
            $("#sp1").html(str);
        }
    });
}
```

Action method in HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetEmpData(int id)
{
    Employee obj = db.Employees.Find(id);
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
Enter your name :
<input type="text" id="t1" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" id="b1" onclick="fn_test()" value="get message" /><br /><br />
<span id="sp1"></span>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct you urls correctly using

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpData", "Home")',
```

and pas the data using

```
data: { id: eno },
```

and remove

```
contentType:'application/json;',
```

Edit

Since your script is in a separate file, modify your html to

```
<input type="button" id="b1" data-url="@Url.Action("GetEmpData", "Home")" value="get message" />
```

Then change the script to

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    cache :false,
    url: $(this).data('url'),
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: $("#t1").val() },
    success: function (response) {
     ...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Now also not working. And getting below error in chrome browser.  "GET http://localhost:1229/@Url.Action(%22GetEmpData%22,%20%22Home%22)?id=101&_=1441254168086 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: After removing 'contentType' also i m getting same error from browser(404)

Comment: 404 means url is wrong,and consider checking your routeconfig

Comment: OK, Do you have this is a separate js file?

Comment: See update (razor code is not parsed in external files, so you need to generate the url in the main view)

Comment: Please check the below code in routeconfig file                                                      public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: @KamaalShaik, Your routes are fine (its just the default setup)

Comment: yes Stephen, and also i tried with your given code. No result. Now i am facing 500 error in browser

Comment: That because you throwing an exception in the controller method

Comment: Looking at your html you have `<input type="text" id="t1" />` with a label to enter your name, but your controller method expects a value which is typeof `int` - don't know too many people whose name is `3` :)

Comment: @KamaalShaik (your need to respond to a user as I have done here!). Not sure why your responding to an answer that does not work, but your now hitting the controller method. If `obj` is null, its because `db.Employees.Find(id)` is not finding an `Employee` whose ID matches the value your passing to the method.

Comment: Just test it by initializing a new `Employee` and setting some properties - `var obj = new Employee(){ EmpName = "abc", Job = "xyz", ... };`

Comment: Sorry Stephen, Yesterday I could not respond to your message. Because that the time to go to office. sorry again. Now i will test and come back to you.

Comment: Yes, Now its working stephen. Problem is in my Employee object only. Thanks a lot. You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

you are passing parameter as query string .you have tell the browser this using ? sign before variable name that you had used in controller and after this you can assign value to this.

```
function fn_test()
    {
        var eno = $("#t1").val();

        $.ajax({
            cache :false,
            url: "Home/GetEmpData?parameterNameInController="+eno,
            type: 'GET',
            data:"",
            contentType:'application/json;',
            success: function (response)
            {
                var str = "Ename :" + response.EmpName + "<br >";
                str += "Job :" + response.Job + "<br >";
                tr += "Salary :" + response.Salary + "<br >";
                str += "Deptno :"+response.DeptNo+"<br >";
                $("#sp1").html(str);
            }
        });
    }


public ActionResult GetEmpData(int id)
{
Employee obj ;
try{
    obj = db.Employees.Find(id);
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}catch(Exception ex)
{ obj=new Employee();
//return empty object
return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

Comment: your parameter type or name is not matching. eg if you controller function has parameter GetEmpData(string id) this would be your query string "Home/GetEmpData?id="+eno

Comment: OP has a route with `{id}` and the method has a parameter named `id` so this is no different form OP's original code

Comment: yes Nasir, My parameter type is 'int' name is 'id'. And i replaced id from your above code

Comment: "Home/GetEmpData?id="+eno use this as your url if you still found error 500 then check model in view and the one you are sending from controller to that view

Comment: i changed my action method parameter type to string and coverted back to int in the action method. no result

Comment: Hi Nasir and Stephen i did debugging now. The parameter value is coming into action method but in json parameter the 'obj' showing null